# "css"method doesn't work for an html image element

Tags: jquery, html

html:

```
<img src="image/wall.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:80%;left:19%" class = "wall">
<img src="image/wall.jpg"  style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:36%" class ="wall">
<img src="image/wall.jpg"  style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:57%" class = "wall">
<img src="image/wall.jpg"  style="position:absolute;top:30%;left:76%" class = "wall">
```

Jquery:

```
var wal =$(".wall");
alert(wal[2].css("left"));
```

When i excute this code console shows an error "  `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'css'` " .Why console gives this error ? and What is it's solution?

Comment: You can't mix jQuery with plain Javascript, you want **.eq(2)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`css()` is a jquery method, use `eq()` instead which returns a jQuery object:

`wal.eq(2).css("left")`

`wal[2]` returns a DOM node {because a jQuery object is an array-like object}, that explains your issue.

Answer (score 1):

A. Wolff's solution will of course work but one of the way I know is

```
var left1 = $(wal[0]).css("left");
var left2 = $(wal[1]).css("left");
var left3 = $(wal[2]).css("left");
var left4 = $(wal[3]).css("left");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naW7Z/